# How do you avoid Goro's teleport/stomp attack?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

Goro has an obnoxious attack where he jumps up off the screen, then comes down and lands on your head. It seems to be unblockable, but I don't actually own him to check his moveset.

How can I avoid this attack? I've tried dashing, but I can't get out of the way fast enough and he still clips the edge of me.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is run towards him best possible outcome is you combo him out of the air. He is usually slow and vulnerable at the point of readying for the jump.

Or Alternatively, stay relatively close to him at all times and jump over his attacks. Pressure fighting against him will be the best defence.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run cancel when you see his jumping animation using the new run mechanics from MKX. It allows you to put that distance between you and the place Goro will land.